# Checking stderr of check_call command and rerunning the command based

Tags: python, python-2.7

am sure there is a better way to write the below code...below are the issues am running into with my current code, please provide any inputs you may have

1. I want to check the stderr of below command and re-run it based on the error message
2. Error mesage looks like "error: Cannot delete the branch "alphanumeric string" which you are currently on,am trying to match like below but running into error

   ```
   import subprocess    
   def main():
   change="205739"
   proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'branch', '-d', change], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   out, error = proc.communicate()
   if error.startswith("error: Cannot delete the branch"):
       subprocess.check_call(['git', 'branch', '-d', change])

   if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
   ```

Comment: you want `==` to test equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want to avoid using `shell=True`, split it out into a list instead and you'll save yourself having to use interpolation to boot.

To test for equality, use `==`; `=` is for assignment only which is not allowed in a `if` statement.

You need to use `.Popen()` if you wanted to check for `stderr` output:

```
import subprocess

def main():
    change="205739"
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'branch', '-d', change], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, error = proc.communicate()
    if error.startswith("error: Cannot delete the branch"):
        subprocess.check_call(['git', 'branch', '-d', change])
```

Comment: what is the issue with using shell=True..also the reason I was using check_call is that I can capture the stderr and do some operations based on it... do you suggest to use open instead of check_call?

Comment: @user1934146: See [Frequently Used Arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) on why using `shell=True` is not a good idea. The `stderr` argument of `check_call` does *not* take a variable as input; it's either `PIPE`, a file object, or, for `stderr`, `STDOUT`, but you cannot really access the return value when using `PIPE` when using `check_call`.

Comment: the code you provided is giving a compilation error ,TypeError: bufsize must be an integer,were you able to compile it?

Comment: I noticed that and fixed it but there an error after that,TypeError: bufsize must be an integer,I updated my code with it

Comment: @user1934146: your code is not a proper copy of my answer. The first argument is a list, just `'git'`.

Comment: Its actually a true copy..I just updated...do you know what is wrong with your code?

Comment: Are you saying you still get the same TypeError?

Comment: Yet my version is only passing in *one* positional argument, and that means `buffer` is left to the default. I do *not* get a TypeError. Tripple-check your code.